# The state information is invalid

Tags: asp.net

I am using a dropdownlist (as a filter) to prepare a sql request and show the result in a jquery plugin (datatables).
When I show the result in the datatable and try to change the selected item in my dropdownlist, it shows the following error :

> Sys.WebForms.PageRequestManagerServerErrorException: The state information is invalid for this page and might be corrupted

What I have noticed is that if the datatable is empty then I can change the selected item without error.
How can I solve the problem ?

Comment: Where's your code?

Comment: http://renditionprotocol.blogspot.in/2007/01/state-information-is-invalid-for-this.html

Comment: It seems that I get the same error on Chrome, I forgot to say that it is working when I am in development on Visual Studio but when I put the files project on my IIS, I get the error.

Comment: If it does work correctly user IIS Express from Visual Studio but it doesn't work anymore on my IIS, isn't it a problem of IIS configuration ?

Comment: I checked and tried the solutions without success

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Datatable was being added to the ViewState and ViewState was too large. I disabled ViewState for this control and it is now working.